# Is it a bad practice to create software that wouldn't work in a historical date?

Tags: language-agnostic

Here is the exact situation that got me thinking about this.

> I have function that automatically
>   generates the next logical item
>   number. Part of that item number
>   includes the year that the item number
>   was created. We are now in the year
>   2010 so the most significant portion
>   of the date (for the purposes of my
>   item number) is "10" and is two
>   characters long. If my program would happen to
>   be executed in 2009, the way that it is
>   current coded, I would get a bad item
>   number because my system is expecting
>   a two digit date (10) not a single
>   digit (9).

My question is not at all about my specific situation and if it is a good idea to be doing this kind of string manipulation or not :) but more on the principle that is stated in my title. Is it a bad idea to write software that will not function properly if ran in history? Have you encountered a similar situation and what route did you take and why?

Comment: In history? Do you mean the past or the future (or both)?

Comment: I mean history past only. We all know about Y2K and all the bad things that happen with not anticipating the future. :-)

Comment: Seeing as time travel is impossible at this time, I would say it is not a consideration. Do you know something I don't?

Comment: You never know when it will be possible! :-) Maybe when we start having time travel we will discover a lot of unknown bugs in existing software that didn't anticipate it...something like Y2K all over again!

Comment: "09" would be two characters long, allowing you to support creation dates in the previous decade.

Comment: Also, 09 is not a date in the past. It is the year 2109. So your specific example will not only fail to work when run in the past but also fail if your code happens to end up being used far longer than you anticipated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to say, "My program will not work with historical data."  In your specific case, "historical data" being stuff prior to Jan 1, 2010.  I disagree strongly with those who say that it's in general a bad idea to place such limitations on your code.

We live with those limitations every day.  The standard UNIX `time_t`, for example, has a range of plus or minus about 68 years.  Applications that store dates and times with `time_t` cannot represent a date before 1901-12-13 or after 2030-01-19.  And yet millions of applications are written using that time format.  But we don't hear anybody arguing that those programs are somehow bad.

Building applications is all about tradeoffs.  If in your best judgement it's not necessary to cover dates beyond some arbitrary point in the past or even in the future, then that's fine.  It's no different than designing a system that will only hold X number of records or deploying with a 1-terabyte drive knowing that eventually you'll have to upgrade when your data grows.  The fact is that we can't design for every eventuality.

Those who argue that the "Y2K bug" shows why you shouldn't place arbitrary limitations on your code aren't thinking things through.  After all, a 4-digit year is also an arbitrary limitation.  What if I want to represent a date 10,000 years in the past or in the future?  That darn Y10K bug!  At some point we place a limitation on the range of things we support.

Every piece of software has limitations.  You select the limitations that are right for your application and how you see it being used in the future.

Comment: You should work in the banking industry for a few months. Requirements such as "let's recalculate our taxes for the past 15 years with this new assumption/ program" are sooo common (and not planned beforehand, of course). Much more common than "let's multiply our clients by 10000", btw.

Comment: Having worked in the banking industry for quite a few years, I'm quite familiar with that kind of thing.  A programmer working in that industry should use his judgement and not select limitations that would make such a thing impossible.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious to readers: The Y2038 problem is not inherent to the standard UNIX definition of `time_t`. It's up to the implementation how big that type is, so you basically have 28 years to stop using implementations with a 32bit `time_t` for current dates, and have perhaps already done so if you're dealing with future dates. Coincidentally, my pension says I retire in 2038, so it's Not My Problem, but my pension provider has somehow dealt with it in at least one context (probably just by using an `int` of years in that case, admittedly).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you heard about [bug y2k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) ? So, yes, it's a bad practice.

Comment: I'm not talking about future dates, we all know about Y2K. My question is about history.

Comment: I'm aiming at the general idea of using part of the date to save 2 int spaces.

Comment: @Bivas: so you are driving at the issue I would encounter come 2100? That is a good point actually, but relates to my specific issue more than the principle.

Comment: @Icode4food the learnings from y2k were not the "be sure to be able to run in the future" kind, but "be sure your code is not date-format dependent". So the Biva's answer applies.

Comment: Good points Bivas and belisarius. My main reasons for keeping it short are A-to comply to my client's age old system. B-to keep it more humanly usable.

Comment: @belisarius: "Be sure your code is not date-format dependent".  Really?  Within what bounds?  After all, we have a latent Y10K bug just waiting for something bad to happen.

Comment: @Jim just be sure your code runs OK with the jewish calendar, or any other, not just gregorian and you'll be on the safe side.

Comment: @belisarius: Even then, your code is subject to the limitations of the underlying date/time representation, which is not infinite.

Comment: @Jim software is a free world. There is no _underlying_ ... you chose one (just be sure to be able to convert it to your client's)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your deployment requirements, but as a general principle this is **definitely** bad practice.

Computer clocks are frequently set wrong, or differently, whether for legitimate reasons* or just because of a battery failure or whatever. Should your program fall over under those circumstances?

And, laughable as the idea that anyone will be using your code in 90 years time may seem, programs can outlive expectations -- years turn and they'll be back to single digits eventually. It's shortsighted to assume the year will never be '01 again.

Basically, locking yourself into the arbitrary happenstance of the present moment just isn't a great idea.

** Eg, to work around issues with other software that made unwarranted calendrical assumptions.*

Answer (score 1):

Grey area. I think it's fine to write code that won't run if the current date is before 1970 (Unix epoc). Before the current year is maybe a bit riskier. Even aside from accidents, there could be good reasons why people have test cases set up with the clock wrong - reproducability and/or date-related regression tests.

If you want a short code that's date-based and won't wrap too soon, then a year is approximately 2^25 seconds, so you could divide the seconds-since-epoc date by that, and take two hex digits. It's somewhat human readable, in that you can tell whether a value is "recent" or not, but it's not so human readable that people will come to rely on it as a 2-digit year.

It lasts beyond the year 2226. Personally I would want to put something in the code either to detect that condition, or preferably to allow it to wrap (i.e. don't assume anywhere that those digits actually tell you the date, just treat them like a hash bucket).

Even with decimal digits, you realise that you could write 2009 as "09", right? There's no need for that to result in a short string ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question depends on how flexible you want you code to be. If you aren't going to update or use this code for anything else and it serves its purpose as of now, it's perfectly reasonable and not necessarily bad practice to program this way. However, if you want your software to be something that could be implemented in other scenarios and not just explicitly perform its original function, this wouldn't be a great idea. The point is from an optimistic enterprise standpoint, don't; from a realistic programming aspect, go ahead.